# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date in sql

Tags: c#, sql, ado.net, prepared-statement, sql-injection

i using am writing a insert statement but getting above error

Insert query

```
var insertSql = string.Format(
                $"INSERT INTO Sales (Date, Team, Sales) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2})",
                new List<SqlParameter>()
                {
                    new("@date", sales.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")),
                    new("@team", sales.Team),
                    new("@sales", sales.Sales),
                });
            var rowCount = Sql.ExecuteNonQuery(Conn,insertSql);
```

here is my table schema and class

```
SaleId int,
Date Date,
Team varchar(50),
Sales int

public class Sales
{
    public int SalesId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string Team { get; set; }
    public int Sales { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use parameterized query to achive this so tried this but giving above error

Comment: show your table definition and object definition

Comment: This isn't a prepared statement at all. It's string interpolation that resulted in SQL injection. String interpolation is no different than concatenation. The specific error is raised because a numeric expression was injected in the `VALUES` clause: eg `VALUES ( 2024-01-13, Barcelona, 13 M)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos can you tell me how to build it

Comment: What is `Sql` in `Sql.ExecuteNonQuery`?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos nit: `VALUES (0, 1, 2)` every time, regardless of the respective values in `sales`: this is a case of "I heard you like interpolation, so I interpolated your interpolation format string"

Comment: @MarcGravell I don't want to know

Answer (score 3):

The *immediate* problem here is that `$"..."` is *itself* an interpolated string, and the values you are injecting are the **literal** `0`, `1`, and `2` - they're not placeholders: *they're the values*. Removing the `$` would make it a literal string suitable for `string.Format`, but *you don't want to use `string.Format` here*; also, you don't want to format the date - just pass it *as a date*.

Honestly: if you're writing the SQL yourself, I'm not sure EF is even needed here; with Dapper this would be simply:

```cs
conn.Execute("INSERT INTO Sales (Date, Team, Sales) Values (@Date, @Team, @Sales)",
    sales);
```

or with a trick for better SQL formatting:

```cs
conn.Execute("""
    INSERT INTO Sales (Date, Team, Sales)
    Values (@Date, @Team, @Sales)
    """, sales);
```

Dapper will deal with finding `sales.Date`, `sales.Team` and `sales.Sales`, and add them *correctly*. EF may also have an API for doing ad-hoc queries like this, but... this *feels* more like a Dapper scenario, unless you're emotionally invested in EF.